# Can't get isNaN function to work properly

Tags: javascript

I've created three text boxes. The first two text boxes are for two numbers (for subtraction). The result will appear in the third text box. I'm trying to make it so that if the user puts in a letter instead of a number, an alert happens.

Right now, the isNaN isn't working. Whenever I put anything in the first or second textbox, it alerts, regardless of number or letter. Here's my code.

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("taxFree"); //textbox 1
    var y = document.getElementById("prodCost"); //textbox 2
    var res = document.getElementById("salesMargin"); //Result textbox

     // If x or y is Not a Number, send alert to user
    if (isNaN(x) || isNaN(y)) {
        alert("Numers only!");
        return;
    } 
    res.value = x.value - y.value;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Paste Your html too

Comment: `x` and `y` are *DOM elements*. They're always not-a-number. You need to convert *their content* to an int explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try checking the `value` of the `input`:

```
if (isNaN(x.value) || isNaN(y.value)) {
```

Comment: You'll also want to provide a radix to avoid surprises: `parseInt(x.value, 10)`.

Comment: But the `isNaN()` method already tries to convert its argument to a number before testing if the result is `NaN`. So how does adding `parseInt()` help?

Comment: @MoisheLipsker Thanks! This helped so much! It's always the little details. Thanks again! I'll mark your answer in a few minutes!

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using this solution, because you don't actually work with numbers. If the expression at the end would be `x.value + y.value` instead, you would get surprising results. I think you cannot bypass explicit parsing overall.

Comment: @TamasHegedus The OP's question seems to be regarding why the condition in the `if` statement is always evaluating to `true`. For the sake of clarity, I'm trying to keep this answer as simple as I can.

Comment: @TamasHegedus Thanks for your suggestion. What "surprising results" are you referring to?

Comment: @MangoPie if `res.value = x.value - y.value;` was instead `res.value = x.value + y.value;`, the code would end up concatenating the two values instead of adding them as numbers. `'5' + '5'` is `'55'`, as opposed to `5 + 5`, which is `10`.

Answer (score 1):

The [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) function tells you if a value equals to the special value [NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN). If it is a string it will try to parse it befor. `isNaN` will not return true for every value that is not a number, for example `isNaN(true) === false`.

The other thing is that you try to call `isNaN` on the input element itself, not its value. Try this instead:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var taxFree = document.getElementById("taxFree");
    var prodCost = document.getElementById("prodCost");
    var salesMargin = document.getElementById("salesMargin"); //Result textbox

    var x = parseFloat(taxFree.value);
    var y = parseFloat(prodCost.value);
     // If x or y is Not a Number, send alert to user
    if (isNaN(x) || isNaN(y)) {
        alert("Numers only!");
        return;
    } 
    salesMargin.value = x - y;
}
```

```html
<input id="taxFree" value="15">
<input id="prodCost" value="10">
<input id="salesMargin" value="x">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Go!</button>
```

Comment: @JohnBurger wrong. Type in `asd` and see what happens.

Comment: @JohnBurger I mean you are right, but you didn't notice the call to `parseFloat`.

Comment: @JohnBurger - the `isNaN()` function tries to convert its argument to a number, and then tells you if the result of that conversion is `NaN`, so `isNaN("abc")` returns `true`. Tamas - Adding `parseFloat()` doesn't really help, because if the user enters `"123abc"` then that will be accepted as the number `123`, which is misleading at best.

Answer (score 0):

I must say this method will not work if you want to know if the entered input is  a number or not.

Try this , this function will only accept numbers from 0 to 9, nothing else at all even decimals not allowed. It does so by checking the entered input's char

code:`onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'`

just add this line to your input as follows:

```
<input id="taxfree" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'>
```

Comment: What if the user puts letters in via the Edit menu or drag'n'drop?

Comment: Yea well it only restricts input, so drag and drop and copy pasted elements get thorugh this filter :(